# Controling Idle Time in Jetty Websocket

Tags: jetty

Hi I am using Jetty 8 for my Websocket server.

I do realize that Jetty supports setting MaxIdletime through API.

However, I want to distinguish this in two ways. 
- Inbound Idle time
- Outbound Idle time.

This is because, if session becomes dummy socket and if a server keeps sending outbounding messages, I figured out it never falls into Idle session.

I see that Mina supports this kind of settings, I wonder if Jetty supports this as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html). consider upgrading.

Jetty 9 does not support separate idle timeouts for the input vs output channels.

As WebSocket is a bi-directional socket which mandates support for half-closed scenarios, having separate idle timeout would only affect that specific channel, and not resolve the fundamental issue you seem to want to address.

What you are calling a "dummy socket" is actually a "half closed socket", which is still a 100% valid WebSocket.

Comment: Of course, it is still valid fd. However, as a server perspective, it is a heavy load to keep having those number of "half closed sockets". What I wanted to control was realize the half closed sockets just by Inbound packets, not considering outbound packets. This is requried in my business...

Comment: What websocket API are you using?  (If you are using the Jetty WebSocket API, and not the javax.websocket API, then you could listen for the close frame and force disconnect the websocket)